Two NextJS applications in separate repositories under one backend
I have two NextJS applications under separate repositories and different domains.
I want the second NextJS application to fetch the first NextJS application's backend code. Backend is graphql + apollo. But I am reaching a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" problem since they have mismatching domains.
Here is a diagram to illustrate my setup. What are the best practices to tackle this issue? Two UIs, two domains, one backend.

On localhost, it works well.
Application A: localhost:3000
Application B: localhost:4000
For application B, NEXT_PUBLIC_APOLLO_BASE_URL is "localhost:3000". But when it switches to the hosted domain, CORS issues arise
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloClientOptions,
  InMemoryCache,
  NormalizedCacheObject,
  createHttpLink,
} from '@apollo/client'
import { auth } from 'app/firebase/clientApp'
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context'
//import { offsetLimitPagination } from "@apollo/client/utilities";
//
//
const apolloCache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    SearchConfigOption: {
      keyFields: ['pathName'],
    },
    Query: {
      fields: {
        /* filterItems: {
          keyArgs: ['user'],
          merge(existing, incoming) {
            if (!incoming) return existing
            if (!existing) return incoming // existing will be empty the first time

            const { items, ...rest } = incoming

            let result = rest
            result.items = [...existing.items, ...items] // Merge existing items with the items from incoming

            return result
          },
        },*/
      },
    },
  },
})

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APOLLO_BASE_URL}api/graphql`,
  credentials: 'include',
})

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const user = auth.currentUser
  const token = user && (await user.getIdToken())
  const modifiedHeader = {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : 'Bearer null',
    },
  }
  return modifiedHeader
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: apolloCache,
  connectToDevTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  credentials: 'include',
})

export default client



The Issue here is that you have to configure the domain of application B in the backend CORS middleware, if you're using an express server for your backend, this is how you would configure it

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['https://merchant-domain.com', "https://application-2-domain.com"],
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const server = new ApolloServer({
  // Apollo server configuration
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/api/graphql', cors: false });

app.listen({ port: 3000 }, () =>
  console.log(`Server ready at http://localhost:3000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);



